# substitution in Z3Py

Tags: python, z3

It seems that the `substitute(f,t)` function in Z3Py performs simplification on `f` first before doing the substitution.  Is there a way to disallow this?

I would like the following behavior to occur:

```
f = And(x,Not(x))
result = substitute(f,*[(Not(x),BoolVal(True))])  #sub Not(x) => True
#if we simplify f first then the result = False,  but if we do the substitution first then result = x
```

Comment: Do you by any chance mean `substitute()`?

Comment: yes, `substitute()`.  I will make the change to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `substitute` procedure is implemented using the simplifier which can apply substitutions during the simplification. The `substitute` Python procedure invokes the Z3 C API `Z3_substitute` in the file [api_ast.cpp](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c430fe26aa30#src/api/api_ast.cpp). Internally, the simplifier is called `th_rewriter` (theory rewriter).

That being said, I agree this is not nice and may be very inconvenient in some cases. I will change that for the next release.